# data attribute won't change after properly selected

Tags: jquery

I tried to change the `data-question_ref` attribute, let's say from `2` to `1`. Below is how I know that this doesn't work.

```
console.log($('#tbl-answer tr[data-question_ref='+(counter + 1)+']').length)
$('#tbl-answer tr[data-question_ref='+(counter + 1)+']').data('question_ref',counter);
console.log($('#tbl-answer tr[data-question_ref='+(counter)+']').length)
```

It prints:

```
2
0 //it should be 2 though
```

Is there something missing here?

Here is similar issue on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgPTR/1623/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use data attribute for reference in jQuery. Data is always updated in memory but the DOM map is not updated. Check the example I made for you that alert the updated data.

http://jsfiddle.net/wgPTR/1622/

If using the data is necessary you can create you filter method like

```
$('#tbl-answer tr').filter(function(){ return (this.data('question_ref') == counter); }).length
```

Comment: Though you didn't answer why my code above doesn't work.. Also if I convert your code to be more similar to mine, it doesn't work.. http://jsfiddle.net/wgPTR/1623/

Comment: I have mentioned that "Data is always updated in memory but the DOM map is not updated" and the jQuery selector works on DOM so it will never work.